# Sshow results where users are following the same id

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, sorry about the question title, i really dont know what i can title this. Any suggestions?

anyway, I am creating a newsfeed kind of site that shows posts and status updates by networks you follow and by users that follow the same networks.

My current sql query is

```
SELECT companyname,post_content,forename,surname,date,type,postertype
FROM cheddar.usernetworks un
LEFT JOIN cheddar.feed f ON f.posterid = un.networkid OR f.posterid = un.userid
LEFT JOIN cheddar.users u ON u.userID = f.posterid AND postertype = 'user' 
LEFT JOIN cheddar.networks n ON n.id = f.posterid AND postertype = 'network'
WHERE un.userid = '9'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

[image]

My aim as I mentioned is to show the results (posts) by the networks themselves and the users that follow the same networks as the user logged into the site. (I've put `9` as the user id in the query for testing).

at the moment it is only showing the posts from user 9 and the network, but no posts from the user `6`.

Any ideas? I've been trying various different things for 2 hours now, and this is the last thing i came up with.

SQL for feed table

```
CREATE TABLE `feed` (
  `postid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `posterid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_content` mediumtext,
  `date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postertype` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (1,9,'hello! meow!','1516889612','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (2,10293,'we are the peaky blinders','1516889612','update','network');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (3,9,'Earned a new badge!','1516901430','badge','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (4,9,'Top Seller','1516901430','topseller','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (5,9,' dddd','1516909119','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (6,9,' lol','1516909164','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (7,9,' haha','1516909214','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (8,9,'Why is GOD so great?','1516909574','question','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (9,9,' Coffee is for closers!','1516909968','tip','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (18,9,' lol','1516915928','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (19,9,' meow','1516916436','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (20,9,' Haha! Was that you?!','1516916487','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (21,10295,'Sell wine! It\'s not a crime','1516916905','update','network');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (22,42,'I love women and sales!','1516916905','update','user');
INSERT INTO `feed` (`postid`,`posterid`,`post_content`,`date`,`type`,`postertype`) VALUES (25,9,' is mo a bad boy','1516926061','question','user');
```

SQL FOR usernetworks

```
CREATE TABLE `usernetworks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `networkid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
*/
INSERT INTO `usernetworks` (`id`,`userID`,`networkid`) VALUES (1,9,10293);
INSERT INTO `usernetworks` (`id`,`userID`,`networkid`) VALUES (4,42,10293);
INSERT INTO `usernetworks` (`id`,`userID`,`networkid`) VALUES (5,3,10293);
INSERT INTO `usernetworks` (`id`,`userID`,`networkid`) VALUES (8,6,10295);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: provide the create table and some data please

Comment: updated question with feed data. Hope this is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f26a0/11)

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f26a0/11/0)**:

```
| id | userID | networkid |
|----|--------|-----------|
|  1 |      9 |     10293 |
|  4 |     42 |     10293 |
|  5 |      3 |     10293 |
|  8 |      6 |     10295 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT f.*, post_content,date,type,postertype

FROM usernetworks un
LEFT JOIN feed f ON f.posterid = un.networkid OR f.posterid = un.userid
WHERE un.userid in (
  select u1.userID 
  from usernetworks u1
  inner join usernetworks u2 on u1.networkid = u2.networkid
  where u2.userID = 9
)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f26a0/11/1)**:

```
| postid | posterid |              post_content |       date |      type | postertype |              post_content |       date |      type | postertype |
|--------|----------|---------------------------|------------|-----------|------------|---------------------------|------------|-----------|------------|
|     25 |        9 |           is mo a bad boy | 1516926061 |  question |       user |           is mo a bad boy | 1516926061 |  question |       user |
|     22 |       42 |   I love women and sales! | 1516916905 |    update |       user |   I love women and sales! | 1516916905 |    update |       user |
|     20 |        3 |      Haha! Was that you?! | 1516916487 |    update |       user |      Haha! Was that you?! | 1516916487 |    update |       user |
|     19 |        9 |                      meow | 1516916436 |    update |       user |                      meow | 1516916436 |    update |       user |
|     18 |        9 |                       lol | 1516915928 |    update |       user |                       lol | 1516915928 |    update |       user |
|      9 |        9 |    Coffee is for closers! | 1516909968 |       tip |       user |    Coffee is for closers! | 1516909968 |       tip |       user |
|      8 |        9 |      Why is GOD so great? | 1516909574 |  question |       user |      Why is GOD so great? | 1516909574 |  question |       user |
|      7 |        9 |                      haha | 1516909214 |    update |       user |                      haha | 1516909214 |    update |       user |
|      6 |        9 |                       lol | 1516909164 |    update |       user |                       lol | 1516909164 |    update |       user |
|      5 |        9 |                      dddd | 1516909119 |    update |       user |                      dddd | 1516909119 |    update |       user |
|      3 |        9 |       Earned a new badge! | 1516901430 |     badge |       user |       Earned a new badge! | 1516901430 |     badge |       user |
|      4 |        9 |                Top Seller | 1516901430 | topseller |       user |                Top Seller | 1516901430 | topseller |       user |
|      1 |        9 |              hello! meow! | 1516889612 |    update |       user |              hello! meow! | 1516889612 |    update |       user |
|      2 |    10293 | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network |
|      2 |    10293 | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network |
|      2 |    10293 | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network | we are the peaky blinders | 1516889612 |    update |    network |
```

Comment: Thank you @blag. I've learned a lot from this. Appreciate it.

Comment: @ScottO'connor you're welcome ;) you can try to refactor the query to use only inner join insted of the `in` + sub-querry